# How do I set up gitolite to have repositories directory on a network drive?

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite

I am trying to set up a Windows 2003 Server as a git server.  I am attempting to install gitolite in order to manage my repositories.  The problem I'm running into is that I want to set up my repositories on a network drive for space reasons along with other considerations.  I can't figure out for the life of me how to manage this task.  When I edit the gitolite.rc file to change the directory to map to my e:\repositories folder where I want it to go I get an error.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.  I'm open to other solutions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended using openssh and COPSSH.  What a pain.